# Double nationality - leaving/entering Europe with ID card

Tags: customs-and-immigration, france, russia, dual-nationality, borders

I have a booked flight (cannot cancel it), my passport is expired and I cannot renew it in time. Also I have a double nationality, in fact I am a Greek, born in Russia and living/working/studying in France since 14 years. I am planning to go to Russia to see a close family member which has some medical issues.

So the flights are:

- first France (where I work and live) =>Russia
- then Russia => France (where I work and live)

Documents that I have:

- Valid Greek Id card
- Valid Russian passport
- Expired Greek passport of more than 3 months

So I have no doubt about entering/leaving Russia with the valid russian passport, but I'm not sure about entering/leaving France with just an Id card.

It is said that there is no problem for traveling between European countries with an Id card, but what about leaving/entering European borders?

Comment: I think you can travel within the EU (and enter) with a valid national card (issued from any other EU country). But have that expired Greek passport as well to show. What I'm not sure if which passport should be registered for the flights and if it's possible to register the Russian one.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ "But have that expired Greek passport as well to Show" Absolutely no need

Comment: @Crazydre I know it is not needed. But it is asked by some customs agents. I entered Heathrow for example and they didn't particularly like my 10-year old Greek ID card (admitting, not in perfect condition). They would have let me even if I hadn't shown the recently expired passport but who knows how much delay a grumpy agent might have given to me.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Like I said, it's mainly because they have to tap stuff in on the Computer by hand

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ "What I'm not sure if which passport should be registered for the flights " You don't Register the passport flying from France to Russia. At the gate though, you use the document to be used for the Destination country

Comment: It looks like you attempted to edit your post, but you created a [new account](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/63372) instead of logging in with your [existing account](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/63368). You might want to visit the *[Merging Accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)* help page.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/84409

Comment: See my update with a link

Answer (score 16):

Your Greek ID card alone is valid for entering/exiting any EU/EFTA country, regardless of where you're flying to/from.

Present your documents as follows:

- At French exit control, your boarding pass, Greek ID card and Russian passport (the French usually require to see the papers for your destination before letting you out).
- At Russian entry control, the Russian passport.
- At Russian Exit control, the Russian passport (and Boarding pass+Greek ID Card if asked)
- At French entry control, your Greek ID Card

You can leave your expired Greek passport at home

**Proof**: As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=GR&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=FR&EM=RU&selDest=France&selTrans=Use%20ctrl-key%20to%20select%20or%20deselect%20transit%20point%28s%29%20above&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C), the database used by airlines:

> France: Passport Exemptions:
>   - Nationals of Greece with a national ID card.

Comment: Is this true if the ID card is issued by a member state different from the one the OP is a national of?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Any EU national can enter the EU, but you're not supposed to be allowed on a plane with such a card

Comment: +1, great answer, especially the steps to take along the way. Is there a reason why they should leave their Greek passport at home? Will it compromise them in some way?

Comment: @GayotFow It is expired, hence only ballast ...

Comment: @Crazydre I think that depends on the country, and the concern is entirely the airline, that the destination country will not let the person in and the airline will have to take them back. But several countries outside the EU DO let certain EU nationals in without a passport and only an ID card, so travel to those should be allowed. You can enter Turkey on just a French ID card, for example.

Comment: They will of course let you board if you have the documents to enter your destination country. Showing the Russian Passport (meaning he is legally in Russia) and the Greek ID (meaning he is also allowed to enter France) is sufficient.

There is no need that the exit and entry document is the same.

Comment: @IvanMcA An EU or Schengen national can always enter and exit an EU or Schengen country, full stop. Nothing to do with the other country's rules

Comment: @CrazyDre I was addressing your "but you're not supposed to be allowed on a plane with such a card".

Answer (score 12):

No problem whatsoever. The site requires me to write more but that's really all there is to it. You can enter every EU country, even countries that do not themselves issue ID cards (that's the UK, Denmark, and Ireland, although Ireland recently introduced a “passport card”), with a valid national identity card issued by another EU country. It doesn't matter if you are currently coming from inside or outside the EU.

Comment: Inside your parentheses, "it" refers to UK, Denmark, Ireland, or all three?

Comment: @anonymous2 Ireland has passport cards, not the other two

Comment: Okay, gotcha.  Just wasn't sure I was following the grammar.  :)

Comment: Is this true even if the identity card is not issued by the member state the holder is a national of?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I know some countries use a somewhat confusing terminology and there are a few difficult situation like non-citizens in Baltic countries but my understanding is that such a document would not be “national identity card” at all.

Comment: @Relaxed: Hmm, I got the impression that the OP is a Greek national but the ID card he talks about is issued by France where he lives. But I see now that the question doesn't really say that in so many words.

Comment: (I know, for example, that Italy issues _carte d'identità_ to EEA citizens resident in Italy -- but those cards bear a "not valid for travel abroad" notation.)

Comment: @HenningMakholm That's the one “confusing terminology” I had in mind. I am positive you won't find anything like that in France, which is why I assumed the ID is Greek.

Comment: The potential problem being that the airline staff in Russia might not know that the ID card is sufficient... perhaps in Russia they are aware enough, but there are many different countries further out that are not used to the concept of national cards being sufficient for entry.

Comment: @FooBar That's what Timatic is for - at least someone there will probably know enough English to read it

Answer (score 3):

Here are some update about the travel:

On the way in (France =>Russia). I always showed only russian passport and had no question about the second nationality.

On the out (Russia => France). During the checkin they asked me to prove that I can enter EU so I showed my greek ID card. They were not so happy about the fact that it had more than 10 years of emission but I told them that the Greek Id has no expiration. At the end they were not happy but finally let me checkin.
At the borderpass of Russia I showed only Russia passport.
At the borderpass of France I give them Greek Id card + expired Greek passport and Russian passport. The guy just opened the russian passport and put a stamp in it without looking my European documents.

Comment: The French police officer did **not** do it correctly. He should've checked your Greek ID (+optionally the expired passport) and not stamped any document. It seems he automatically assumed you were showing a residence permit rather than an ID card, without actually taking a look. But whichever way works! Just for the future, you would only have needed the Greek ID at the French border.

Comment: I was also surprised by this, but it was early in the morning and I was in the middle of a Russian crowd, so I guess he did all the things without thinking so much. Moreover I've seen a significant difference between French and Russian border control. The Russians check each thing on the passport and ask questions whereas the French ones seems to not care that much.

Comment: The French are very lazy - they often don't even stamp passports from the US, Canada, Australia Singapore and other "low-risk" countries, which is illegal on their part and can give you a living hell if trying to exit through Germany, the Netherlands or Switzerland (for example).

Comment: In any case, for the future: you **only** need to show your Greek ID card to the French (doesn't matter where you're travelling to/from), not your Russian passport. Your expired Greek passport can be left at home. Any embassy/officer that says otherwise is plain wrong.

Answer (score 1):

So here are more informations. I called the French border control center. They told me that I should be able to pass the border but I may encounter a longer document control. They also added that I should avoid indirect flights.
Moreover, I found here in this link that we can travel with expired passport and valid Id card:
http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/expired-lost-passports/france/index_en.htm
It concerns The French documents and leaving from France, but there's not the case of leaving France with Greek ID.

Comment: So again some more information. I called the Greek consulate. They told me that for the travel France-> Russia, there's not problem, but for the travel Russia-> France, they were not sure.
So from all the informations I am 95% sure that I would be able to enter Russia, but have no clue about entering Europe.
Anyway, my flight will be in one month, I'll inform you if I pass or not.

Comment: "No clue about entering Europe": as an EU citizen, you have a legal right to enter the EU.  Your Greek ID is proof of your EU citizenship.

Comment: And if I were with you, I would still keep the expired Greek passport while travelling. It's an additional proof of your citizenship, though expired.

Comment: Yes, I will take many documents just in case. I will take also my French driving licence, a Greek proof of birth and a Greek paper that says that I am permanent citizen of France. Those documents might have no value abroad, but you never now.

Comment: @sk245230 My God, you've been speaking to complete amateurs, who've made you concerned for absolutely no reason. With a Russian passport, you have the **legal right** to enter Russia, and with a Greek ID card (proof that you're an EU citizen) you have the **legal right** to enter France (an EU Country), **full stop**. It can take a bit longer at French border control, yes, because entering a Greek ID card's data takes about 15 seconds by Hand instead of just scanning it

Comment: @sk245230 And by the way, you shouldn't ask the Greek consulate about French requirements, since they have no say in it. French border Police, yes, but what the Greek consulate says means absolutely zero